# MediaPlayer "Couldn't open <url>"?

Tags: java, android, youtube

I did search and tried all solutions found on Stack / Android documentation or tutorials

Any idea why I can't play a video URL (from YT for example) inside a VideoView into my app?
Added INTERNET permissions inside AndroidManifest file, also this is the part of my code:

```
String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+eventData.getYoutube_id();
final VideoView vw = views.getVideoView(R.id.vw_media);
vw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

try{
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(context);
    mc.setAnchorView(mc);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
    vw.setMediaController(mc);
    vw.setVideoURI(video);
catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
vw.requestFocus();
vw.start();
```

I get a message in app that say "Can't play this video"
[image]

**Logcat:**
MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfkmKzr8zgg: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfkmKzr8zgg

Can't fix this at all..
Btw, Android version is 7.0

Comment: If you have youtube video id then use YouTubePlayerFragment (YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi) instead of VideoView

Comment: I would, but this part of the code is not inside of an activity / frame . . And I can't integrate it without extending YoutubeBaseActivity class.

Answer (score -1):

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AlertDetail.this, "", "Loading Video wait...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FJHYqE0RDg";
            videoUrl = getUrlVideoRTSP(url);
            Log.e("Video url for playing=========>>>>>", videoUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Login Soap Calling in Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(AlertDetail.this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
        mc.show();
    }

}

public static String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube)
{
    try
    {
        String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
        URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
        Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");///media:content
        String cursor = urlYoutube;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            if (node != null)
            {
                NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++)
                {
                    Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                    maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                }
                if (maps.containsKey("yt:format"))
                {
                    String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                    if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                    {
                        cursor = maps.get("url");
                    }
                    if (f.equals("1"))
                        return cursor;
                }
            }
        }
        return cursor;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
    }
    return urlYoutube;

}

protected static String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException
{
    String id = null;
    try
    {
        String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
        if (query != null)
        {
            String[] param = query.split("&");
            for (String row : param)
            {
                String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                if (param1[0].equals("v"))
                {
                    id = param1[1];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (url.contains("embed"))
            {
                id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
    }
    return id;
}
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/sfkmKzr8zgg

Comment: i managed to workaround with your solution, and the result is the same "Can't play this video"..

Comment: ya, i'm still getting an error. i'm currently looking into exoplayer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Answer (score -1):

Add this after mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

```
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build());
```